# ASP.NET Find id of selected row from datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist in my ASP.Net web form. The datalist has an image button and a hyperlink. These things are kept in the item template in the datalist. I want to get the id of the row in which the image is clicked. Here is my ASP.Net code

```html
<div height="100%" width="100%" class="w3-center">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" >
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image_path") %> '  CommandName="Item" CommandArguement='<%#Eval("Catg_Id") %>' Height="200" Width="350" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Concat("SelectedCatg.aspx?category=",Eval("Catg_Name")) %>'/><br />
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Concat("SelectedCatg.aspx?category=",Eval("Catg_Name")) %>' CssClass="link" Font-Size="18"><%#Eval("Catg_name") %></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

I have itemCommand event but it doesn't catch the event on clicking the image button.

```
 protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);

        String index=e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/SelectedCatg.aspx?id=" + index);
       /* if (e.CommandName.Equals("img"))
        {
            int AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString());

        }*/
    }
```

Need help.
Thanks

This is how I bind my datalist

```
         String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString();
         con = new SqlConnection(conString);
         con.Open();
         String query = "Select * from Category_Master";
         cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Load(dr);
         DataList1.DataSource = dt;
         DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Try `CommandArgument` instead of `CommandArguement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try which command was fired? check this and let me know the result please.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Item") 
            {

                int index= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 

               Response.Redirect("~/SelectedCatg.aspx?id=" + index);


            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show how you bind DataSource of DataList? @KishanShah

Comment: @KishanShah is it on every postback, right? like 
if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         //bind datasource
    }